$W_{10t}^2 - W_{5t}$ is not gaussian
I want to show that the process $X_t = W_{10t}^2 - W_{5t}$ is not gaussian, where $ (W_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is a Wiener process. I can calculate its characteristic function to see that it is not of the right form, but the calculations are quite tedious. So I was wondering, is there a simpler argument, like in the case of the process $X_t = W_t^2$, where we can just say that it cannot be gaussian, because $\mathbb{P}(W_t^2 < 0) = 0$?

Set $$W_{10t }-W_{5 t} =a, W_{5t}=b$$ and determine the moments of $$(a+b)^2 - b$$ with $a,b$ independent Gaussians with the speciality, that the 2n-moments are powers of the second moment with factors of $(2n-1)!!$.
